# Как перевести число из 15-ричную системы в 10-чную?

Tags: c, файлы, системы-счисления, текстовые-файлы

Добрейшего дня всем кто это читает!

Задание вот такое: "Средствами текстового редактора создать файл, в каждую строку которого записать 15 код длинного целого числа. Разработать функцию, которая вычисляет десятичное значение длинного целого числа, 15-й код которого хранится в заданной символьной строке (библиотечные функции преобразования "строка – число" не использовать). Используя разработанную функцию, извлечь из файла строки, значения кодов в которых меньше заданного пользователем границы LMIN"

Помогите создать алгоритм, который будет переводить 15 код числа записанного в строке одного файла в 10 код, и потом записывать этот 10 код в другой файл.

Заранее всех благодарю

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUFSIZ  255

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    FILE* input, * output;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    size_t nread;
    const char *fname1 = "C:\\Users\\user1\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\fcode\\rcode.txt";
    const char *fname2 = "C:\\Users\\user1\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\fcode\\ncode.txt";

    input = fopen(fname1, "rb");
    output = fopen(fname2, "wb");
    while (nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), input)) {
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), nread, output);
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если это текст -0 то что вы его так странно читаете/пишете?...

Comment: Ну деление столбиком в цикле, а потом переврнуть результат.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь развернутой формой записи числа:
[image]